# @Cacheble and @Scheduled to start at same time in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, jwt, scheduling

**Preface:** The requirement in a product (a bunch of spring boot applications), I am working is to use JWT Tokens for security, fetched from an internal server, and use it to communicate amongst services via REST calls.

**Problem:** The JWT Token TTL is exact 2 hours, so I tried to put it in a cache, so that for a given `userId`, I should not fetch a new JWT Token from the server before it expires. This part works, the issue was to evict the cache when the TTL expires.

The code is as follows.

```
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

public class JWTUtility {

    // Some Fake JWT Ticket
    private static final String FAKE_JWT_TICKET = "";

    @Cacheable(value = "jwtToken", key = "#userId", condition = "#userId != null")
    public String getToken(boolean securityEnabled, String userId) {
        if (!securityEnabled) {
            return FAKE_JWT_TICKET;
        } else {
            // Proper logic to fetch and return the JWT token from Server
            // Assume this works
        }
    }

    // JWT Ticket TTL is 2 Hrs, scheduling cache evict at 1:50 Hrs
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 6600000)
    @CacheEvict(value = "jwtToken", allEntries = true)
    public void evictJWTTicketValues() {
        //Intentionally left blank
    }
}
```

The scheduling part does not work as I was expecting it to. The question is how to start the timer of the scheduler as and when some JWT ticket for a particular `userId` enters the Cache `jwtToken`. I am open to refactoring/re-writing logic for the above `JWTUtility` class entirely.

Comment: If you're open to using other cache providers than the default one in Spring Cache (which is an in-memory HashMap, I believe,) you can set up an eviction policy in for example ehCache. Personally, though, I've stopped trying to use Spring Cache for this, and just fetch the token from a map that contains the token and its expiry. Then I can check if I need to retrieve a new one.

Comment: By the way, if you consider evicting the whole thing every 2 hours or so, also consider that every 2 hours you might get a jump in the average response time, and a rush of new calls to the token provider. Which may or may not be a problem, but it's worth mentioning. You will also notice that tokens that have just been issued will sometimes be discarded because they were issued right before the cache was evicted.

Comment: @Thomas Kåsene, Thanks for the insights. 1. I first thought of using a simple HashMap < K -> Object{String: userId, OffsetDateTime: startTimestamp},  V -> String: JWT Ticket >, but my seniors asked me to use something from Spring here. 2. I agree with these performance concerns. But this is allowed in this application, the product being asynchronous, uses Kafka for most of the communication, the REST calls are quite seldom.

Comment: I was thinking more something like `Map<String, {LocalDateTime, String}>` so as to keep the key as simple as possible. `String` implements the `hashCode`-method quite well. Anyway, I guess you can try to do something with the `TaskScheduler` instead of the `@Scheduled`-annotation. You should be able to inject the `CacheManager`-bean into a `RunnableTask`, which calls its `clear`-method.

Comment: @Thomas Kåsene, Thanks for the suggestion. I will try using this `TaskScheduler ` with `CacheManager`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Thomas Kåsene pointed out - if you can use other cache provider then you can set the eviction policy, while configuring the cache. Below is example for configuring [Caffeine Cache](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-caffeine) :

```
@Bean
  public CaffeineCache jwtTokenCache() {
    return new CaffeineCache(
        "jwtTokenCache",
        Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(120, TimeUnit.MINUTES).recordStats().build());
  }
```

You need to declare annotate your method as -

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "jwtTokenCache", value = "jwtToken", key = "#userId", condition = "#userId != null")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to use some dependency from Spring internal only.
`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>`
Is not acceptable as per constraints.

Comment: Check if this resolves your issue - https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2017/01/25/setting-ttl-for-cacheable-spring/